# Switching from Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Desktop to Server version

Tags: server

I just updated to the new version of Ubuntu, 18.04.1 LTS. I have a Samba server, apache server, ftp server, and a OpenSSH server installed, along with a lot of files. If I ever want to switch out of the GUI mode and use the server version, how do I go about doing that **without losing any files**. I have heard of taskel, but is it any good for my case.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yeah I know it is, but i just wanted to know if there is something like this.

Comment: I haven't done this in ages, but a `sudo systemctl stop gdm` should stop your gui from operating, and `sudo systemctl disable gdm` will disable it for subsequent boots.  (*this is based on my using 18.10 now with multiple DEsktops loaded, and a quick `ps` scan showed `gdm` in control; your system may be different*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the GUI from operating you can use (current session)

`sudo systemctl stop gdm`

(if you were using Xubuntu which uses `lightdm`, you'd replace `gdm` with `lightdm`)

To make this effect subsequent reboots, you use

`sudo systemctl disable gdm`

To start replace `stop` with `start`, to re-enable replace `disable` with `enable`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check this command out. But one quick question, does it just switch to a command line as soon as you type in this command, or does it just not display anything at all?

Comment: I've never tried using it from a gui (for safety, I'd always want to be logged out of gui anyway).  I login to terminal (ctrl+alt+f4) and run it from there.  I wasn't willing to test it on this 18.04 box, but tested the start|stop part of it on a 18.10 box next to me.

Comment: Okay I booted a 18.10 live image (xubuntu x86), opened a terminal and used the `sudo systemctl stop lightdm` (as xubuntu uses that & not gdm), the result was just the end of gui & a blinking cursor. (same on both screens; evidence to me the gui had ended & i was stuck on a inactive terminal)  I then had to press CTRL+ALT+F4 to switch to a terminal & login to continue using the machine.  *f4 could be another key; it's just my default*

Comment: so I am guessing that CTRL+ALT+F4 is the best way to go about doing this then? And not using the command specified above.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "*not using the command specified above*".  There is no point using `disable` on a 'live' system (I tested the disable in gui mode using the latest 'daily image'  of the upcoming 18.10 release I use for testing purposes), as rebooting (where disable will take effect) means a new 'live' system is booted. I wasn't willing to test my answer on a real system (I was using at the time & still using now).  The commands will work, but my suggestion is doing them from real terminal so you're not left with a blinking cursor on all screens (due to killed gui).

Comment: alright now, I think I understand now. Thank you for your help.